# Checking Whether a textbox is empty?

Tags: php, textbox

Hey guys i'm trying to make a php script check whether or not the text boxes are empty, i am using the below code.

```
<?php
$dbname = $_POST['db_name'];
$dbuser = $_POST['db_user'];
$dbpass = $_POST['db_pass'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($dbname == "" || $dbuser == "" || $dbpass == "" || $username == "" || $password == "")
{
Echo("Missing Information!");
}else{
Echo("Success!");
}
?>
```

Below is my form code:

```
    <form method="post" style="padding-left: 50px" action="install_submit.php">
<h2>Database connection settings</h2>
<label for="db_name">Database name:</label>
<input type="textbox" id="db_name" name="db_name" /><br/>
    <label for="db_user">Database username:</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="db_user" name="db_user" /><br/>
<label for="db_pass">Database password:</label>
<input type="password" id="db_pass" name="db_pass" /><br/>
<h2>CPanel settings</h2>
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="textbox" id="username" name="username" /><br/>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br/>


<input type="submit" name="submit_install" value="Install" />
</form>
```

With that it always returns "Missing Information!" even when all the text boxes are filled in.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do `print_r( $_POST )` to check there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 7):

Use `empty()` instead,

```
if (empty($dbname) || empty($dbuser) || empty($dbpass) || empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    //Empty
}
else {
    //Not Empty
}
```

Check to see that the **`name`s** of the inputs are correct as well.

Comment: Didn't work but i added my from code to original post if that helps.

Comment: Your code (copy/pasted and tested on local development environment) works fine.

Comment: Make sure you accept the correct answer if it worked for you @DuncanP

Answer (score 0):

For debugging try to do a

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to see what you actually receive in the $_POST variable and then try one comparison at a time in your if statement.
Maybe it makes you see behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace this & check whether you get all parameters value or not.

```
<?php
$dbname = $_POST['db_name'];
$dbuser = $_POST['db_user'];
$dbpass = $_POST['db_pass'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
die();

if($dbname == "" || $dbuser == "" || $dbpass == "" || $username == "" || $password == ""){
    echo("Missing Information!");
}else{
    echo("Success!");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the posted data u can use `isset()`.

**Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL**

```
if(!isset($dbname) || trim($dbname) == '')
{
   echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}
```

`trim()` keyword remove white spaces which are ignored by `empty()`.